# Inconsistency with creating link symbol for never defined static member object

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, language-lawyer

This is rather classic question "who is right, GCC or clang, and where to fill an issue?".

Recently I've met a code which used some kind of tag dispatching which can be brought down into:

```
struct X {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

struct A {
    static const X x;
};

int useX() { return A::x.value; }
```

There are two core things: recommended pattern to access `X::value` is by `A::x.value` (since `X` is some ugly templated type), but `static X x` is never defined. It doesn't really bother compilers, as they are able to guess `.value` from `x` type. But `clang` creates missing symbol entry in case of shared object with optimization disabled (`-O0`).

Call to `clang++ --shared so.cpp -o so.so -O0 -fPIC && nm -C -u so.so` results on my machine with:

```
w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
w __gmon_start__
w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
U A::x
```

Using `g++` or `-O1` will get rid of `A::x`.

Is `clang` right here to require definition of `A::x`? It sounds like that based on point [11.3.8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#1).

> A static member may be referred to using the class member access
>   syntax, in which case the object expression is evaluated

Thus `object expression` require an object to be evaluated on.

But, even if clang is conforming standard, then there is internal inconsistency between `-O0` and `-O1`, right?

Or maybe is this topic out of scope of Standard and it is simply implementation-defined?

Comment: If the only reason to use the static member is to avoid typing `X` (with a longer name), then a simple solution should be to use a type alias instead.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks, I agree, but I am not owner of this interface and the code itself is generated. I asked this question to learn why this issue even came up in the first place. I have fixed it locally by using `decltype(A::x)` and filled an issue in author's repository.

Comment: This smells like ODR violation and it is ill-formed, NDR. I think this permits "inconsistency" between different optimization levels.

Answer (score 0):

If `A::x` is odr-used, then it must be defined somewhere in the program. However, no diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule. ([[basic.def.odr]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#11))

There is often a way to ask the compiler whether a variable is odr-used, in a way that *does* require a diagnostic: try to use it inside a lambda expression without capturing it, and see whether the compiler complains. So, here's our test program:

```
struct X {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

int foo() {
    X x;
    return [] { return x.value; } ();
}
```

Note that I've replaced the undefined static member `A::x` in your original program with a local variable. This doesn't really change the answer to the question. The crux is whether or not `E1.E2` odr-uses `E1`, where `E1` is an *id-expression* of class type, and `E2` is a member enumerator.

The big 4 [agree](https://godbolt.org/z/v4M7fna1o) that this program is ill-formed; `x` is odr-used by the lambda and has not been captured. [[basic.def.odr]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10.sentence-2) makes it ill-formed (diagnostic required) to odr-use a local entity in a scope in which it is not "odr-usable". `x` is not odr-usable because it is not captured by the lambda.

Since we have pretty strong evidence that `x` is odr-used, we now look at the wording that makes it so. [[basic.def.odr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5) states:

> A variable is named by an expression if the expression is an *id-expression* that denotes it. A variable `x` that is named by a potentially-evaluated expression *E* is *odr-used* by *E* unless
>
> - `x` is a reference that is usable in constant expressions ([expr.const]), or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and *E* is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied, or
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type, and *E* is an element of the set of potential results of a discarded-value expression ([expr.context]) to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

`x` is not a reference, so the first bullet point doesn't apply. Keeping in mind that *E* here is the *id-expression* that names `x`, and that *E* is just "`x`" (the expression, not the variable), our algorithm is as follows:

- Determine the set *S* of expressions that have *E* as a potential result (defined in [basic.def.odr]/3).
- For each element *ex* in *S*, check whether the second or third bullet applies.

  - The second bullet applies if `x` is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, **and** *ex* has non-volatile-qualified non-class type, **and** the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied to *ex*.
  - The third bullet applies if *ex* is a discarded-value expression to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

If the second or third bullet is found to apply for *any* *ex*, then `x` is not odr-used here. Otherwise, `x` is odr-used.

So first we have to compute the set *S*. According to [[basic.def.odr]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#3.1)), an *id-expression* has itself as a potential result. The larger expression `x.value` does not have `x` as a potential result, because neither p3.3 nor p3.4 applies here. (p3.3 applies to non-static data members. p3.4 applies to static data members.)

So in the algorithm above, the only *ex* that we need to consider is `x`.

The second bullet doesn't apply, because the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied to `x` in the expression `x.value`. Nothing in the language requires it to be applied, so it's not. [expr.ref]/1 merely says that "the postfix expression before the dot or arrow is evaluated", and this yields a glvalue referring to `x`.

The third bullet doesn't apply, because `x` is not a discarded-value expression either, despite the fact that its value is literally discarded. An expression is only a discarded-value expression if the standard explicitly says so ([expr.static.cast]/6, [expr.comma]/1, [stmt.expr]/1).

So there is no exception that applies here, and `x` is odr-used. Arguably, it shouldn't be, but that would require a proposal to amend [[expr.ref]/6.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#6.5) to say that `E1` is a discarded-value expression.

In the original program, `A::x` is odr-used by the same logic, and it must be defined. If your compiler and linker sometimes allow you to slip by without a definition, it doesn't mean that your program is well-formed.